# How does getChild() and getChildCount() work?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am making a plugin for this model:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<sdf version="1.4">
  <model name="my_model">

    <link name="link">
      <gravity>true</gravity>
      <inertial>...</inertial>

      <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>2.0</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>640</width>
            <height>480</height>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>1.0</near>
            <far>15000</far>
          </clip>
        </camera>
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        <visualize>1</visualize>
      </sensor>

      <collision name="collision">...</collision>
      <visual name="visual">...</visual>
    </link>

    <plugin name="myplugin" filename="libmyplugin.so"/>
  </model>        
</sdf>
```

In the plugin I want to manipulate the pose of the camera.
The code I use to do this is:

```
gazebo::physics::BasePtr base = _model->GetLink()->GetChild(std::string("camera"));
if(base){
    boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<gazebo::sensors::CameraSensor>(base)->SetPose(pose);
}
```

Interestingly `base` always ends up being a `nullptr`.

When I call

```
_model->GetLink()->GetChildCount()
```

I get the children count of `1`.

If I call

```
_model->GetLink()->GetChild(0)->GetName()
```

I get `"collision"`. So it seems like the only children to the `<link>` is the `<collision>`. This seems quite unlogical for me and I am stuck. I also tried adding another collision tag to the model SDF, GetChildCount then increases to `2`, and both collisions can be listed. Is there something about the semantics of `GetChild()` that I do not understand? I thought I could manipulate the camera using it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15431/how-does-getchild()-and-getchildcount()-work?/) by [lysgaard](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1254/lysgaard/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `gazebo::physics` library deals with [physics entities](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Entity.html), such as models, links and collisions. Therefore, when you get a child entity, you get one of these physics objects.

Sensors are handled by a separate library, `gazebo::sensors`. I can see how that can be confusing, but even though the camera sensor is a child of the link in SDF, it isn't a child for the physics library. The maximum the physics library can give you is the name and number of sensors, but no pointers. Take a look at these functions:

- [physics::Link::GetSensorCount()](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html#a8d2ae8d2524611509688907d5bb9ee46)
- [physics::Link::GetSensorName()](http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Link.html#adf6ae4d4af962b76b9d4c49b4212b7c0)

To get a pointer to the camera sensor, you'll have to use the sensor library like this for example:

```
auto camera = sensors::SensorManager::Instance()->GetSensor("my_model::link::camera");
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lysgaard](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1254/lysgaard/) on 2017-02-14**:
Thanks for the good answer.
Might I suggest that the `GetChild()` and `GetChildCount()` documentation is updated to include a note about it's limitations, and maybe even a link to other possibly wanted functions like `GetSensor()`?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-02-14**:
Sure, I created an issue for that: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2194/improve-api-documentation-for-getchild